# Solidity: Returns filtered array of structs without 'push'

Tags: solidity

I have this contract with an array of structs:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Tickets {
  struct Ticket {
    uint id;
    int val;
  }

  Ticket[] tickets;

  function addTicket(uint id, int val) public returns(bool success) {
    Ticket memory newTicket;
    newTicket.id = id;
    newTicket.val = val;
    tickets.push(newTicket);

    return true;
  }

  function getTicket(uint id) public view returns(Ticket memory) {
    uint index;

    for(uint i = 0; i<tickets.length; i++){
      if (tickets[i].id == id) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    Ticket memory t = tickets[index];

    return t;
  }

  function findTickets(int val) public view returns(Ticket[] memory) {
    Ticket[] memory result;

    for(uint i = 0; i<tickets.length; i++){
      if (tickets[i].val == val) {
        result.push(tickets[i]); // HERE IS THE ERROR
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

I need to returns a filtered by `val` array but when I buil this code: `result.push(tickets[i].id);` it throw this error:

`TypeError: Member "push" is not available in struct Tickets.Ticket memory[] memory outside of storage.`

How I can implement the filter without using `push` ?

Answer (score 11):

Returning dynamic-length array of struct is still a bit tricky in Solidity (even in the current 0.8 version). So I made a little workaround to make it work even in the 0.6.

1. Determine the result count, you'll need it for step 2.
2. Create a fixed-length array
3. Fill the fixed-length array
4. Return the fixed-length array

```
function findTickets(int val) public view returns(Ticket[] memory) {
    uint256 resultCount;

    for (uint i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++) {
        if (tickets[i].val == val) {
            resultCount++;  // step 1 - determine the result count
        }
    }

    Ticket[] memory result = new Ticket[](resultCount);  // step 2 - create the fixed-length array
    uint256 j;

    for (uint i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++) {
        if (tickets[i].val == val) {
            result[j] = tickets[i];  // step 3 - fill the array
            j++;
        }
    }

    return result; // step 4 - return
}
```

Comment: This is useful (as far as I've been learning for now), but it is double the cost. there must be a better way.

Comment: @JuanVilar I'm sure there is going to be a more straightforward and cheaper way in the future.  The latest version of Solidity is currently (November 2021) 0.8.9, which can be also interpreted as "unfinished", as it's lower than 1.0.0. So we can still expect some major changes and upgrades to the language before the version 1 is released.

Comment: @JuanVilar Also, the code in my answer is wrapped within a `view` function. Which means, it doesn't modify the contract state and can be called from an off-chain app using the `eth_call` method (i.e. doesn't require a transaction). Calls are gas-free, you only pay gas for transactions. So in this particular case, the two loops use double processing power of the node (compared to using just one loop), but the gas cost is still zero.

Comment: Was just working on this problem over the weekend and I can confirm that there's no straightforward way to do it with just one loop right now. You can't get around having to create that fixed size memory array, and figuring out how many have to go into it before you declare it. :(