# solidity: returns(string[] memory) won't permit return of string[5]?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm wondering why if my function is meant to return a string of indeterminate length, I can't return a string array of definite length.

This function, for example doesn't compile

```
function BindingTypeList() public pure returns(string[]  memory) {
        return ["DocumentTemplate", "Definition", "RepAndWarranty", "Restriction", "Entitlement"];
    }
```

the error message is `TypeError: Return argument type string memory[5] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) string memory[] memory.`

It seems like they are saying that `string[5]` is incompatible with `returns(string[])`. I don't get that at all. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to return a dynamic array (`string[]`), but in fact the `return` statement instantiates a fixed array (`string[5]`).

Quick fix: Return `string[5] memory` (instead of `string[] memory`).

---

Solidity is currently (v0.8) not able to resize an in-memory array. So you can't just define an empty dynamic array in memory and then `push()` into it. But there's a workaround to return a dynamic array containing the predefined list of items:

You can define a dynamic array with 5 empty items, and then re-assign their values.

```
function BindingTypeList() public pure returns(string[] memory) {
    string[] memory arr = new string[](5); // 5 empty items
    arr[0] = "DocumentTemplate";
    arr[1] = "Definition";
    arr[2] = "RepAndWarranty";
    arr[3] = "Restriction";
    arr[4] = "Entitlement";
    
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Oh, fantastic.  For some reason I thought string[]memory arr = new string[](5) would create a fixed length array too

Comment: Thats all fine and good if you know the size of the returned array. But what if you don't?

Comment: @CliffHall For dynamic-size array, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233439/1693192). You need to calculate its final length first, then declare the dynamic array with N empty items, and then it's the same as in this answer.