# Member "push" is not available in bool[] memory outside of storage

Tags: solidity

I was trying a simple push operation within solidity.
As shown in the code below with function isArrayEven():

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

contract Test {
    uint[] public arr = [uint(1), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9];

    function isArrayEven() public view returns(bool[] memory) {
        bool[] memory ret;

        for (uint i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            ret.push((arr[i]%2 == 0));
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

But the following error is thrown:

> Member "push" is not available in bool[] memory outside of storage.

I have figured out how to fix this by using below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

contract Test {
    uint[] public arr = [uint(1), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9];

    function isArrayEven() public view returns(bool[] memory) {
        bool[] memory ret = new bool[](arr.length);

        for (uint i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            ret[i] = (arr[i]%2 == 0);
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

But I don't understand this behavior, why is 'push' not allowed for memory arrays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solidity: Returns filtered array of structs without 'push'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616895/solidity-returns-filtered-array-of-structs-without-push)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Memory arrays with dynamic length can be created using the new operator. As opposed to storage arrays, it is not possible to resize memory arrays (e.g. the .push member functions are not available). You either have to calculate the required size in advance or create a new memory array and copy every element.
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays

Comment: Very concise and clear explanation, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use the new keyword while initializing array and instead of pushing it to the array we can initialize it on its position as we have the index in coming from the for loop.

pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

contract Test {
uint[] public arr = [uint(1), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9];

```
function isArrayEven() public view returns(bool[] memory) {
    bool[] memory ret = new bool[](arr.length);

    for (uint i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = bool((arr[i]%2 == 0));
    }

    return ret;
}
```

}