# Explain this solidity statement

Tags: solidity

I'm new to solidity and I came across the following statement:

```
address[] memory path = new address[](2);
```

Someone please break it down for me. Specifically, what does `new address[](2)` do?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It initializes new dynamic-length array variable called `path`

- items are of type `address`
- the array is stored in `memory`, non-persistent data location that is accessible only during the transaction

The right-side of the expression `new address[](2)` initializes the array with 2 empty items.

In Solidity, there is a difference between dynamic-length and fixed-length arrays. So if your function is expected to return `array[]` (dynamic-length), the compiler doesn't allow you to return `array[2]` (fixed-length).

Because of how the memory is structured, it's not possible to resize an array in memory. (However you can resize a storage array.) So this approach is used when you need to return a dynamic-length array. You need to initialize it in memory first with a predefined amount of empty values, and then rewrite those values. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233439/1693192) for a code example.

Comment: In many tutorials I've come across they use `address[] myArray;` (for dynamic arrays) and `address[2] myArray;` (for fixed-size arrays). Why and when do we need to use `new`? I think that's what is not clear to me

Comment: @TheMonarch The `new` keyword is used in 2 cases: 1) Deploying a contract from within a contract (the factory pattern): `OtherContractType variableName = new OtherContractType(constructorParams);`. Do not confuse with asssigning a pointer to an existing other contract **without** the `new` keyword: `IOtherContract variableName = IOtherContract(itsAddress);` ... 2) Right-side of the expression instantiating an array (as in your question). I agree that the `new` keyword might be misleading here, as it's not used in instantiating a `struct` or other object-like types. Hopefully it gets unified.

Comment: I'm quite comfortable with it's usage when deploying new contract instances as you mentioned in the first case. What's unclear is the second use case, are there specific situations when to use `address[] myArray = new address[](2);` as opposed to `address[2] myArray;`?

Comment: @TheMonarch The first snippet declares a **dynamic-size** array, and the second snippet declares a **fixed-size** array, both with the length of 2. These are two different types. The [docs page](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/types.html#arrays) covers it in more depth than I'm able to fit in a comment but feel free to ask about any specifics that might be unclear.

Comment: The docs state, *Memory arrays with dynamic length can be created using the `new` operator. As opposed to storage arrays, it is **not** possible to resize memory arrays (e.g. the `.push` member functions are not available).* which implies they are more fixed than dynamic and the use of the word dynamic is a bit misleading (imho). That notwithstanding I get the idea, it's more clearer now. Thanks @Petr Hejda